Creating custom c++ type qualifier
I want to have a custom type qualifier called "integration". A type qualifier that acts like const, in the sense that it does nothing except adding limitations. Useful limitations to avoid specific bugs. In reality, it can be anything, a macro, template, class.
Only thing that integration should have, are the following features:

Doesn't change the underlying type's operators at all, except that they take in integration version and return integration version

If possible, removed in the final .exe


Should give a compile error when:

Attempting to set integration variable with a non-integration variable

Attempting to construct or set non-integration variable with an integration variable

Attempting to construct or set an integration variable in non-integration function

Attempting to pass an integration variable as argument to a non-integration function

Attempting to call a integration function in non-integration function


First two compile error requirements are quite easy to create: (although this requires every single operator to be remade)
https://onlinegdb.com/l9xEe4o_r
The function requirements feel impossible, obviously I could have a context checking function, but that's a check that needs to be added manually, instead of the compiler realizing something is a miss. It might be possible with macros? No idea though.

Why template <typename U> explicit integration(const integration<U>& other)  and static_assert(std::is_same<T, U>::value instead of just integration(const integration& other) (no static_assert)?

I think you could use an enum class to do this.  You would have to hand write out all the operators you want, but int + enum_class_obj will fail naturally since enum classes do not decay into their underlying type.  Down side is this only works if you want an integer type.

the ideal scenario is that it would work with (at least) every mathematical type, not just integer

I used integration<std::string> with your code (with the obvious changes), and it worked.  The operators should check if the wrapped type supports that operation.

@TedLyngmo With your suggested change, integrated<T> would be constructible from integrated<U> and T deduced to be integrated<U> when !std::is_same_v<T, U>.

I think you should consider why do you want a construct like this. You say in your question that it is to avoid specific bugs. What bugs could be avoided with this approach, which could not be handled with judicious use of const directly? Having a special qualifier, be it a macro or template class, sprinkled around your code, which changes behaviour based on your build type, will not be easy to understand IMO.

@mitch_ it splits all program logic to two, one branch where integration is allowed, and all the other branches where it is not

@WeijunZhou Re: "integrated<T> would be constructible from integrated<U>" -  How do you mean? If T is left deduced, it'd invoke the copy constructor and T would be deduced to U. If Tis explicitly specified to something else than U, it's a compilation error. This is what I'd start with, but there's a lot of nice things one can add of course.

@TedLyngmo Thank you for your clarification. That seems to work.

@fiqcerzvgm "one branch where integration is allowed" -- what does integration in this context actually mean?
